# "Compile Error: Variable does not exist" but I've declared it in the line above

Tags: apex, trigger, before-trigger

I'm trying to create a trigger that will trigger on the conversion of a lead to a contact. It will set a checkbox of another object, the 'Tracker' to True. I've created THE simplest way of doing it (or so I believe), but when I hit "save", it throws a compile error, namely that the valuable "currentiterable" is not declared. See my code below. Does anyone know what's causing this?
Thanks in advance,
Tim!

```java
trigger updateConvObject on Lead (before update) {
 for(Lead lead:System.Trigger.new) {
  if (Lead.IsConverted) 
   LeadTracker__c currentiterable = [SELECT Id, convToOpp__c FROM LeadTracker__c 
                                       WHERE Email__c = :Lead.email LIMIT 1][0];
   boolean isConverted = [SELECT Id, convToOpp__c FROM LeadTracker__c 
                            WHERE Email__c = :Lead.email LIMIT 1].convToOpp__c;
   currentiterable.convToOpp__c  = true;
 }
}
```

Comment: Multiple queries in a for loop. I suggest you do a bit of research about trigger best practices.

Comment: @AdrianLarson, I'll look into it :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should put `{` and `}` around the code block below the if.

As it is now, the if only applies to one line of code, the one directly following it. And so the declaration is not visible to the following lines.

Comment: And this is exactly why I have a rule that optional braces are not optional!

Comment: Thanks for this! I'm new to Java altogether, coming from predominantly PHP

Answer (score -3):

```
trigger updateConvObject on Lead (before update) {
 for(Lead lead:System.Trigger.new) {
  if (lead.IsConverted) {
       LeadTracker__c currentiterable = [SELECT Id, convToOpp__c FROM LeadTracker__c WHERE Email__c = :Lead.email LIMIT 1][0];
       boolean isConverted = [SELECT Id, convToOpp__c FROM LeadTracker__c WHERE Email__c = :Lead.email LIMIT 1].convToOpp__c;
        currentiterable.convToOpp__c  = true;
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: At first I thought this was an exact copy/paste of the OP's code, and did not understand why you would do that. It took some time, but I finally discovered the difference. *THIS* is a good illustration of why "code dump" answers are almost always unhelpful, are frowned upon - and most likely why someone downvoted your answer. If you think this is a good solution, please edit your answer to add the "why" (the explanation of the differences & the reason you think this will work) to go along with the "how" (your code). Here on SFSE the *why* is often as or more important than the *how*.